# ¿Hola alguien me puede auxiliar con este Frame en Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo dos problemas 1ero de que cuando ejecuto RUN no me ejecuta la interfaz grafica, la tengo que ejecutar desde SUMA.java donde dice projects
y lo segundo es que cuando calcula la suma me vuelve a abrir otra ventana nueva de la interfaz.

```
public class SUMA extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form SUMA
     */
    public SUMA() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        CajaTotal = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        CajaNum1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        CajaNum2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jPanel1.setLayout(null);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("SUMA DE DOS NUMEROS");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(110, 20, 240, 22);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Captura el segundo  numero");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(10, 160, 260, 22);

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Captura el primer numero");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel3);
        jLabel3.setBounds(10, 80, 220, 22);

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("TOTAL");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setBounds(50, 220, 150, 40);

        CajaTotal.setEditable(false);
        CajaTotal.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        CajaTotal.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CajaTotalActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(CajaTotal);
        CajaTotal.setBounds(250, 220, 100, 40);

        CajaNum1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        CajaNum1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CajaNum1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(CajaNum1);
        CajaNum1.setBounds(250, 70, 100, 40);

        CajaNum2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        CajaNum2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CajaNum2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(CajaNum2);
        CajaNum2.setBounds(250, 150, 100, 40);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 465, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 351, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         
        SUMA  ventana=new SUMA ();
        ventana.setVisible(true); 
        int Num1, Num2, Total;
       Num1=Integer.parseInt(CajaNum1.getText());
       Num2=Integer.parseInt(CajaNum2.getText());
       
       Total = Num1 +Num2;
       
       CajaTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Total));
       
    }                                        

    private void CajaTotalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void CajaNum1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      
    }                                        

    private void CajaNum2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        
    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SUMA.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SUMA.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SUMA.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SUMA.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SUMA().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField CajaNum1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField CajaNum2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField CajaTotal;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Habria que ver tu codigo para saber que pasa...

Comment: pon el codigo en la pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: No se como hacer para enviarte el codigo

Comment: ahi ya pase el codigo

Comment: solo el codigo del evento cuando calcula, no hay necesidad de todo eso que pusiste

Comment: No entiendo disculpa que es lo que tengo que hacer